# What happens to a Developer Account when I disable 2-Factor Authentication

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, developer-program, two-factor-authentication

The company I work for does not own any apple devices and due to internal reasons not willing to invest in any (Period. Please don't suggest getting an iPhone 5 or similar). I am tasked with the deployment of an iPhone App.

Apple only allows Developer Accounts when they have set up 2-Factor Authentication. That in itself is not a problem, we need to rent an Apple Computer for deployment anyway. My Question is, **what happens when we disable 2-Factor Authentication and return the MacBook**?

I presume I would be no longer able to access the Developer Program, but does the Account itself keep running and the App stays in the AppStore, or am I simply not able to disable 2-Factor Authentication?

Yes, this is not an ideal situation but it is what it is. Does anybody have experiences with this or knows where I can find any answers?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Why do you want to disable 2FA on your Apple ID when returning the MacBook?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So I can just keep the 2FA activated? I was under the impression that via Phone number and via a trusted Apple Device, because just the Phone number doesn't enable me to use a developer account

Comment: Yes. You can and must leave it activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider keeping the 2FA enabled on your Apple ID. It is not required to disable the 2FA on your Apple ID if you do not have any Apple device linked to your account.

In the absence of any trusted device(s) (Macs or iOS/iPadOS devices), you can add a trusted mobile number to your Apple ID account, and can receive 2FA codes via SMS.